# what so special about redis?

Tags: redis, datastore

I mean: [link text](http://code.google.com/p/redis/)

why should one use this over MySQL or something similar?

Comment: IMHO, this explains it quite well: http://www.xtranormal.com/watch/6995033/

Comment: Redis is a cache; an in-memory `key -> value` store. MySQL is an RDBMS they're different technologies for different use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many NoSQL databases, one would use Redis if it fits your needs. It does not directly compete with RDBMS solutions like MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc. One may need to use multiple NoSQL solutions in order to replace the functionality of a RDBMS. I personally do not consider Redis to be a primary data store - only something to be used for speciality cases like caching, queuing, etc. Document databases like MongoDB or CouchDB may work as a primary data store and be able to replace RDBMSs, but there are certainly projects where a RDBMS would work better than a document database.

Answer (score 4):

### SPEED

> Redis is pretty fast!, 110000
>   SETs/second, 81000 GETs/second in an
>   entry level Linux box. [Check the
>   benchmarks](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/Benchmarks).

Most important is speed. No way you can get these numbers using SQL.

### COMMANDS

> It is possible to think at Redis as a
>   **data structures server**, it is not just another key-value DB, see all the
>   [commands](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/CommandReference) supported by Redis to
>   get the first feeling

Sometimes people call Redis Memcached on steroids

Answer (score 3):

This Wikipedia article on [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) will explain.

> These data stores may not require fixed table schemas, and usually avoid join operations and typically scale horizontally.